# CakePHP1.3: incrementing numbers in a paginated view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm displaying a search result obtained via `$this->paginate()` for the view. Pagination works well, and I want to display the row number of the search result for each row on the view for the user. I simply do `<?php echo $i; ?>`, where `$i` is my counter, but on every page, the number starts from 1. So, if I'm on page one of the search result, it will show 1 ~ 10 (10 rows of data per page). I move to page two, and it will still show 1 ~ 10, and so on.

How can I make this so that it shows 1~10 on page one, 11~20 on page two, etc. on the fly? And why does it reset, even though I'm going through my search result array elements one by one and doing `$i++` in every iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `counter()` as part of the Paginator helper.

```
$start = $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => '%start%'));

foreach( $records as $record ) {
  $start++;
  ...
}
```

See if that helps!